# How to export all list data from Web Scope to an excel file?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, export, scope

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can point me in the right direction on how to export all list data from a site to an excel file. Below is what the desired output should be. I've looked online and can't seem to find a good solution for this. I'm looking into a web part but any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

*Edit - Site Owners are going to be using this to generate the reports on their own.

Comment: Why don't you use "export to excel" option directly.

Comment: That isn't exactly what he wants, he is wanting to do that across everything in the site which may be labor intensive to do and update.

Comment: @user2314241 that only works for one list. I need it to pull items from all lists within a site.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "export to excel" option directly.

click on the list title on the ribbon you can find "export to excel"

Comment: That only works for one list. I'm referring to exporting all items from all lists in a site to excel with the format that I displayed.

Comment: In that case you have to go for powershell or jquery to call the lists and than pull data to excel.

Comment: Sorry, and I should have mentioned it in my original post but Site Owners will be using this script to generate the report on their own. PS will not be an option. Thanks for the response tho.